# Mod_Rewrite change GET value pairs into nice slashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url `http://domain.com/module/controller/action/get1/value1/?get2=value2&get3=value3` I want to use Mod_Rewrite to change the `?&=` to appropriate `/` slashes inline with the first `GET` variable.

I also need to avoid conflicts with my current Mod_Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ zend.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify which way you want to convert the URLs? Do the incoming URLs entered by the user have slashes or the classic format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a nice way to do this... so I resolved to write some minimised PHP code at the top of my `zend.php`.

```
list($sURL, $sQuery) = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$sOriginalURL = $sURL;
if ('/' !== substr($sURL, -1)) $sURL .= '/';
if (isset($sQuery)) {
    foreach (explode('&', $sQuery) as $sPair) {
        if (empty($sPair)) continue;
        list($sKey, $sValue) = explode('=', $sPair);
        $sURL .= $sKey . '/' . $sValue . '/';
    }
}
if (isset($sQuery) || $sOriginalURL !== $sURL) header(sprintf('Location: %s', $sURL));
```

If anyone can improve on this please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the GET parameters in their native `$_GET` container, you could leave the htaccess file as is, and have the front controller (I assume you are using PHP) do the parsing and not mod_rewrite.

You would have to access the `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and parse out the parameters before any other URL parsing (I think you are using the Zend Frameworks') kicks in.

This works only if you can modify the part of your program that needs `value1` `value2` `value3` etc. If it's some Zend component that needs the parameters, and that component fetches them directly from `$_GET`, this will not work for you and you may in fact have to build `mod_rewrite` instructions.

Btw, you are aware by the way that with the method in your .htaccess, invalid links to images, CSS files and other media types will all be routed to `zend.php`?

Comment: I need to do it in Mod_Rewrite because I am using lots of built in functions that rewrite the url on the assumption that the GET params are slashed not ?&=... Also, my app deals gracefully with the correct HTTP codes for broken links...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these rules in front of yours:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=([^&]+)&(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%1/%2/?%3 [N]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%1/%2/? [L,R]
```

Comment: Isn't this the wrong way round? I think he wants the incomign URL to be /get1/value1/.... and transform it into GET parameters internally.